# Using ffmpeg to get the actual video resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

Well, this is my first question in this community. I have asked it in SO but it was considered out of scope there.

Anyway, I am trying to decode an avi video but when I pass it through ffmpeg to check the encoding parameters I got this outcome which confused me:

```
$ffmpeg -i video.avi
...
Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2501 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
```

I guess `yuv420p` means something like 746x420 pixel (I made the multiplication myself, so I am not sure it's exactly this one using the ratio of 1920x1080 and 1280x720) but anyway much less than 1280x720 which is 720p. So, what does exactly means those two together?
`yuv420p` vs `1280x720`?

Can someone explain which is the actual resolution of the video (and why I get those different resolutions)?

Answer (score 2):

In `yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]`,

- `yuv420p` indicates the pixel format and [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) scheme.
- the video's raster resolution is simply `1280x720`.
- the video's `S`ample `A`spect `R`atio (width of pixel : height of pixel ratio) is 1:1 (square pixels)
- the video's `D`isplay `A`spect `R`atio is 16:9